# How to delete indices from AWS Elastic search service?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I want to delete  unwanted indices from Amazon Web Services elasticsearch service.

Any idea on how I would be able to do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you know what all the unused indices, then simply use the Elasticsearch [DELETE indices API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-delete-index.html) as below to delete the index.

```
DELETE /twitter
```

Alternatively, you can also use the [Elasticsearch curator](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/5.8/delete_indices.html) to do it.

But IMHO, if there are not many indices to delete and you already know the unused indices, then best is to simply use the delete indices API, which is simple, works and gives your full control.